# Offer free non-consumable items in Apple IAP to some users

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm trying to implement IAP to my app preparing all the code in Swift based in non consumable purchases. Before launching the update I'm thinking about offer like a free reward to some users who help me to promote the app...

For example: My app is based on free filters for photo editing and I would like to implement some new filters to be purchased by 0,99€. Once launched the updated, I'm thinking about asking some Instagramers to promote the app and give to them these filters by free as reward.

Does anyone know if it's possible or permitted on App Store Connect? And if is any code adaptation required in order to prepare the app?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For those who could be in this situation, finally the solution is provided by Apple using Promo Codes: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev50869de4a

Answer (score 1):

Bypass in-app purchase for specific users. iOS doesn't gives option of free in-app purchases. You can also use auto-renewable subscriptions for this which allows trail period.

Comment: Hi @Babar, thanks for your answer! How can I bypass in-app purchase for specific users? Sorry but I'm totally new in the IAP world...